# Organisms in food deposits

Tags: microbiology, species-identification

I have just discovered that my kitchen sink pipe has been leaking for quite some time (possibly months) which has resulted in water and food deposits collecting in my cupboard.

I smeared some of the residue onto a slide and looked at it under my microscope. I could see a large number of **translucent organisms** (visible at **40x magnification**, they are **roughly 100 µm in length**). They all appeared to be of the same species although they varied in size and developmental stage. The 'adults' are **quite long and look similar to maggots; they scrunch their bodies into balls and then stretch out in order to propel themselves.**

Unfortunately I lack the equipment to take a photo of it but **here's a rough sketch** of what it looks like moving to the right:

[image]

Don't take the features *too* literally.

Can anyone hazard a guess as to what it might be?

Comment: Can you make an image of this organisms?

Comment: @Chris I have updated my question.

Comment: http://www.colorado.edu/eeb/EEBprojects/FiererLab/Flores_etal_2012_kitchens.pdf

Comment: I cannot help to answer your question, but I admire your action of taking swabs instead of freaking out after discovering this fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like Euglena but I need more parameters than what you have provided.

[image]
<sub>(source: [eastmarinedrive.com](http://www.eastmarinedrive.com/contents/images/learn/biology/euglena3.jpg))</sub>

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHZZKwrYm4g

you can narrow it down by this:

http://goo.gl/XTEZ7S

Or

You can find them in commonly found microorganism in kitchen:

http://www.colorado.edu/eeb/EEBprojects/FiererLab/Flores_etal_2012_kitchens.pdf

Or

http://www.plosone.org/article/info:doi/10.1371/journal.pone.0078866.t001/largerimage

Source: http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0078866

Comment: Euglena are certainly very similar! Although they don't scrunch up and move like those that I observed. I will look through this list when I get some spare time, thank you.